# Unable to connect to public PostgreSQL RDS instance

Tags: networking, postgresql, amazon-rds, rds

I created a basic test PostgreSQL RDS instance in a [VPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_cloud) that has a single public subnet and that should be available to connect over the public Internet.  It uses the default security group, which is open for port 5432.  When I try to connect, it fails.  I must be missing something very straightforward—but I'm pretty lost on this.

Here’re the database settings. Note that it's marked as *Publicly Accessible*:

[image: RDS Settings]

Here’re the security group settings. Note it's wide open (affirmed in the RDS settings above by the green "authorized" hint next to the endpoint):

[image: Security Group settings]

Here's the command I'm trying to use to connect:

```
psql --host=myinstance.xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
     --port=5432
     --username=masteruser
     --password
     --dbname=testdb
```

And this is the result I'm getting when trying to connect from a [Mac OS X v10.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite) [MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) (note, it's resolving to a 54.* IP address):

```
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "myinstance.xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (54.xxx.xxx.xxx) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I do not have any kind of firewall enabled, and am able to connect to public PostgreSQL instances on other providers (e.g., [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku)).

How can I troubleshoot this?

Here are the inbound [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) rules for the *default* VPC:

[image: Network ACL configuration]

Comment: Did you happen to mess with the NetworkACLs?  I would look there for a possible setting that could be blocking internet access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  The ACLs appear to not be blocking anything, since the first rule is to allow all ports from all sources, per attached.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The issue was that the inbound rule in the Security Group specified a security group as the source.  Changing it to a [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) that included my IP address fixed the issue.

Open the database security group in AWS; and choose "Edit inbound rules"; "Add rule". There is a "My IP" option in the dropdown menu; select that option to auto-populate with your computer's public IP address in CIDR notation:

[image: Edit security group, edit its inbound rules, add a rule, choose "My IP" option in the "Source" column]

Comment: For anyone who doesn't know how CIDR works; if your IP address is 91.61.76.202 (can find yours using http://www.myipaddress.com), set your source as 91.61.76.202/32

Comment: Would you be willing to take a screenshot of what this solution looks like?

Comment: I would be happy to, but I no longer have this instance online.

Comment: Still valid answer in 2024

Answer (score 18):

I was facing similar issue, and this is how I resolved it:

Click on the security group for the RDS instance and check the inbound rules. You might see something like this:

[image]

You have to set the IP address range to contain your IP address  or just select "Anywhere" in the Source dropdown, to make it accessible from [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) or anywhere:

[image]

Comment: Yes this works. I kept the Custom rule that was there and added a new rule which picked up my IP address automatically.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue while connecting to PostgreSQL.  Even though i had publically access true, i was not able to connect.

I added one rule inbound rule in the security group and now it is working perfectly fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add my findings to save someone some time.

This solution described above worked on a development [EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) instance, but after I migrated to a new server, it stopped working. It turned out both of my RDS instances and EC2 instances were in the same VPC, so the RDS instance could not see the public IP address that I had added to its security group.

To get this working, you need to add to the RDS instances security group, the private IP address of the EC2 instance that you can find in details.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a database (or restoring it from a snapshot), it is important to specify the database parameter `"Public access" = "Yes"`