# How to connect to a publicly available RDS instance using Sequel Pro

Tags: amazon-vpc, rds

I'll preface that, yes, I know best practice says to use a bastion host or similar...

I'm trying to connect to an RDS instance through Sequel Pro but unable to.

- The rds instance has been made publicly available
- The Security group allows connections inbound from a specific IP on the db port
- The VPC group is allowing connections inbound/outbound for all

Sequel Pro returns:

> MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'mybd.randomstring.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (4)

What am I missing? Is it an AWS setting or one in Sequel Pro perhaps?
The following have not answered the question:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/612227/connect-database-with-sequel-pro
- [unable to connect to public postgresql rds instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/656079/unable-to-connect-to-public-postgresql-rds-instance)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to remove the port on the endpoint (the :3306 part) and add it down into the Sequel Pro connection pane part.  It is a standard connection with your .pem key file embedded in the connection pane (no Certificate or CA Cert noted).