# How to connect to AWS RDS through DBeaver

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I have a MySQL database on AWS. Here are some of the settings:

- DB instance id - database-2
- Endpoint - database-2.***.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com
- Port - 3306
- Public accessibility - true
- DB name - testdb
- Master username - admin

Now I am trying to connect to that database using DBeaver. Here is the screenshot of the settings I used:

[image: settings I used].

I am getting "connection timed out" error. I tried with `Database: testdb`, but I get the same error. What can I do to fix that?

**Note**: DBeaver works fine with other databases.

Comment: Also, please edit the image into the post, as I am not allowed to post images

Comment: Have you confirmed that your firewall is allowing you to connect? Port / IP allowed. You do have a firewall in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the reason was inbound rules set for security group. Here is a detailed answer about that: https://serverfault.com/a/656119/567809

The proper connection details for DBeaver for me were:

- Server Host: `Endpoint address`
- Port: `3306`
- Database: `DB name`
- User name: `Database master username`
- Password: `Database master password`